# Authenticate with Oauth2 to read IMAP in C# MVC web-application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, imap, dotnetopenauth, mailkit

I would like to read e-mails from a signed in user using IMAP.

I have created a console application for testing purposes and making sure the app-registration settings in azure are correct.

The console application is working as intended.

1. A Microsoft login window is shown where the user can enter their credentials.
2. An access token is received and is passed to MailKit in order to get the user's emails.

**The problem**

When I try to authenticate using MailKit in a MVC .net standard web-application, I get an  error saying "Authentication failed".

However, when I copy the access-token I acquired using the console- application and use it in my web-application I do not get the authorization error and can successfully authenticate and read emails. (I use the access-token as second parameter in
`var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("[Email here]", oathToken.access_token);`).

I have used [DotNetOpenAuth](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-outlook-com-imap-web-applications) in order to show a Microsoft login window.
(I could not find a MSAL example for a web-application where i didn't have to add OWIN as middleware. I only want to authenticate in order to get emails, not for application wide authentication and authorization.)

Console application code (this works):

```
             // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0

             // Configure the MSAL client to get tokens
            var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
             {
                 ClientId = "[client-id here]",
                 AadAuthorityAudience = AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs,
             };

            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

            var scopes = new string[] {
                 "email",
                 "offline_access",
                 "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" };

            // Make the interactive token request
            var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authResult.Account.Username, authResult.AccessToken);

            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
                }

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
```

Web-application (this doesn't work):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string clientID = "[client-id here]";
        string clientSecret = "[client-secret here]";
        string redirectUri = "[redirectUri here]";

        AuthorizationServerDescription server = new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
            ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20,
        };

        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
           "email",
           "offline_access",
           "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
        };

        WebServerClient consumer = new WebServerClient(server, clientID, clientSecret);

        OutgoingWebResponse response = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(
        scopes, new Uri(redirectUri));

        return response.AsActionResultMvc5();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Authorized(string code, string state, string session_state)
    {
        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
            "User.Read",
            "offline_access"
        };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Host", "https://login.microsoftonline.com" },
            { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            { "client_id", "[client-id here]" },
            { "scope", string.Join(" ",scopes) },
            { "code", code },
            { "redirect_uri", [redirectUri here] },
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "client_secret", "[client-secret here]" },
            { "state", state },
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);


        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var oathToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OathToken>(jsonString);

        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("[Email here]", oathToken.access_token);
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            try
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
                }

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);

                return Content(stringBuilder.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Content(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

The problems occurs on this line: `await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);`
I receive an error saying "Authentication failed"
However, when using the access-token from the console application in the web-application i do not get this error and can successfully authenticate and read emails in the web-application.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the "email" scope.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work in my web-application?

Comment: @jstedfast do you have a link to more information on how to set scopes?

Comment: Nope. You just gotta read the documentation for the specific OAuth provider you are trying to interoperate with.

Comment: @abc54 - What you are passing authToken.Account.UserName?